# Question locks considered harmful

Tags: discussion, locked-posts

I love Stack Exchange. I love the fact the community tries to keep questions on-topic. But I think locking of questions should be reconsidered.

My example is this Stack Overflow question: [*"Best C++ Code Formatter/Beautifier"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841075/best-c-code-formatter-beautifier), which I feel **VERY** strongly about.

The thing is that this is the top result in Google when I search for `C++ code formatter`, and it is severely outdated and thus is spreading misinformation - in the recent years a far supreme tool has come out - `clang-format`.

The thing with information on technology is that unlike wine it does **NOT** get better with age - it becomes harmful in this rapidly/constantly evolving young industry.

So I found no direct way of contacting the administrator who locked it (which is fine with me), so I am turning to you guys. **This question should be either deleted or unlocked**.

And maybe when a question is off-topic or is not in the spirit of Stack Overflow, the poster should have a little penalty (increasing with each next felony) or something like that - you can figure out the right way - but the current approach is BAD for some of the locked questions...

**EDIT**: (added a possible answer to the Stack Overflow question)

> [clang-format](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) is a
>   powerful **command line** tool bundled with the clang compiler which
>   handles even the most obscure language constructs in a coherent way.
>
> It can be integrated with Visual Studio, Emacs, Vim (and others) and
>   can format just the selected lines (or with git/svn to format some
>   diff).
>
> It can be configured with a variety of options listed
>   [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html).
>
> When using config files (named `.clang-format`) styles can be per
>   directory - the closest such file in parent directories shall be used
>   for a particular file.
>
> Styles can be inherited from a preset (say LLVM or Google) and can
>   later override different options
>
> It is used by Google and others and is production ready.

Comment: A few points to make here. First, locked questions in general are not harmful. I do not think the generalization the title implies is correct. Second, that post does seem to be out of date and perhaps should be considered for moderation. Perhaps simply posting a comment on the top answer and posting your own answer would have sufficed if not for the fact that the post is locked. In fact, the accepted answer is a community wiki, and as such would be eligible for editing in the new "far supreme tool" as an option.

Comment: @TravisJ I have 7k rep and I can't edit this question / answer so I don't think onqtam will be able to

Comment: @TobyAllen - That is because it is locked :) I cannot edit it either actually, so I edited my above comment.

Comment: @TravisJ My point exactly.

Comment: If the post is out of date, it should simply be deleted. It has served its purpose, lets clean it up.

Comment: *"And maybe when a question is off-topic or is not in the spirit of SO the poster should have a little penalty"* This already happens. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/244864

Comment: There is another newish variety of lock, [the so-called "wiki answer"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182566/this-lock-notice-is-partly-misleading/182572#182572), that might be appropriate for this question. It allows editing of the answer (usually all but one of the answers are deleted and all the information is agglomerated there) but not the question.

Comment: I may be in the minority, but I prefer the lock rather than delete.  From a database perspective, its basically a soft delete.  Keep everything, but flag the old ones as locked, so you've alerted users that its old, but allow them to view the info as well.  Harmful?  I don't think so, but I do believe that if a user with enough creds wants to unlock and add an updated answer, that should be allowed.

Comment: @Radiodef: If people downvote, close and delete bad content in a timely manner, instead of upvoting, yes. But that question will not count against anyone.

Comment: @Deduplicator Isn't that more or less nonseqitur though since the question here was posted in 2009? Nowadays these questions seem to get downvoted and closed pretty quickly. (Unless the OP is suggesting to penalize retroactively...)

Comment: @Radiodef: Many are simply ignored to wither on their own. Others are answered, the answers often being upvoted regardless (and the answerers often upvote as a matter of course), which means the question will stay. And then some are shot down fast enough... and I'm not sure what standards prevailed when the question was asked. Naturally retroactive punishment would bee a horrible idea.

Comment: None of the information in that question is incorrect as far as I can tell.  AStyle still works fine for me.

Comment: I went ahead and consolidated all of the decent answers into the top (community wiki) answer and added yours in as well.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That question wasn't being maintained by the community, so I locked it. The only answers added between 2009 and 2013 were three people who used it to promote their own projects. One of them is a broken link and another was a commercial product. *All* of the other answers were little more than link-only responses, so none of this is the kind of high-quality content Stack Exchange is looking for.

The question remains locked, not deleted, because there are many other pages that link to it. If you want to give me a canonical link for clang-format, I can edit the top answer to include that along with all of the other answers, but I don't think the question should be unlocked. (I'm not ruling out deletion, I just want to see what other people think before I go to the trouble of cleaning it up either way.)

Comment: That many pages link to it is not, I don't think, a good reason not to delete it. In fact, if it's harmfully outdated, this would seem to be a stronger reason _to_ delete it! We should not be afraid of 404s where 404s are warranted.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit I agree, but it's not my decision. The system blocked me from deleting it when I tried.

Comment: heh, you just need to ["fix" 4 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/841075?sort=hot) and you are set to go. BTW, there are some questions that would need some "fixing" too ;).

Comment: @Braiam There are 26 posts on that list. Not all of them can just be deleted.

Comment: You are misinterpreting me. Some of those questions, by current standards (the only one asked recently is OT) would be closed, most of them were asked before mid-2012 (the sed question and the one closed doesn't count). If you see something that, um... you would close if you see it in the /newest tab, just close it. Leave the other questions.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I added in my post a possible answer to that Stack Overflow question. However no matter how this is resolved I think there is an issue that does not concern only this particular case. What do you think? Shouldn't question locks in general be revisited? Or should people continue to look to meta to complain on a case-by-case basis when the urge becomes big enough...

Comment: @onqtam No, I don't think question locks in general should be revisited. They're very rarely used, and only on questions that are extreme corner cases. Revisiting locks would essentially *be* looking at locked questions on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: I almost wonder whether that's warranted here. Maybe.

Comment: [how to deal with link rot caused by deletion of popular off-topic questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125172/165773)

Comment: There is a ton of outdated material on the internet. Anyone doing research on the internet with any kind of common sense should know to check the date of the material they are reading. Often old outdated material leads me to google terms for newer up-to-date searches, so my vote would be to just leave the question alone in its current locked state. It would of course be nice if someone maintained the question, but failing that I'd still rather it exist than to have all my research efforts lead me to the same 404 page.

Comment: @Rachel I agree. I think the maintenance of this question looks pretty low, so I'm probably going to just punt the decision down the road by updating it once  and keeping it locked. We can decide if it should be deleted in another few years.

Comment: @BilltheLizard agreed - Update it once in any way you see fit. I have come to realize that such locked and *a bit* outdated questions are actually rare...

Comment: @Rachel you are overestimating the capacity of people to check dates. I have seen many, *many* users using >5 years old guides, tutorials, etc. for stuff that there are official wiki's with the most updated information. tl;dr: people don't read.

Answer (score 12):

I agree; there must be some way to revisit old protected / locked questions when they get out of date.

I understand we don't want 150 this-is-my-favourite-utility answers, but I can't even upvote / downvote answers to this question anymore.

There could even be a mechanism to flag a question like this to be reopened unprotected, etc. so that a new answer can be added and fight with the others to be upvoted.

Comment: Alternatively, let's delete it all together. The whole reason we don't allow questions like this is that they're opinionated and hard to keep up-to-date. Making them opinionated and *literally impossible* to keep up-to-date was clearly the wrong move.

Comment: @ChrisHayes I'm ok with it being deleted, and also ok with adding a mechanism to SO to vote for an unlock/delete of a question because this is not the only such instance.

Comment: @ChrisHayes I'd prefer a moderator unlocks it, such another answer can be added. Other code formatters mentioned there are still in use and frequently asked for.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps, we can do a sole community wiki answer, like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python) question (same context almost - locked because its off topic, but has historical significance)

Answer (score 0):

To address your stated concern,

> The thing is that this is the top result in Google when I search for
>   C++ code formatter, and it is severely outdated and thus is spreading
>   misinformation

I suggest we expand the warning in the "locked" template (my emphasis to show added text):

> This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is
>   not considered a good, on-topic question for this site **and does not
>   contain current information as it can no longer be edited to reflect
>   latest developments in technology etc.**

Comment: There's a saying in my country: the fever isn't in the sheets.

Comment: If you are going to do something like that, at least use **might not** rather than **does not**.

Comment: @Braiam: Uh, what? I'm not entirely sure I catch the thrust of your country's aphorism.

Comment: @NathanTuggy the most nearest equivalent in english is "curing the symptom, not the cause/illness". The problem isn't the message, is the whole locking process that keeps the worst of the worst of SO and then users can't do anything about it.

Comment: @Braiam: Ah, gotcha. Can't say I disagree, either.