# Is it possible for some "Too Broad" questions to be exceptions to the rule?

Tags: discussion, questions, vote-to-close, close-reasons, needs-more-focus

I randomly came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37361145/deoptimizing-a-c-program).

It's *obviously* too broad: **there are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format** (see the first answer, which has more than 15k characters).

Of course, it's an interesting question, and those who posted answers put a lot of effort into them.

That being said, is there some kind of "exception to the rule" allowed for specific cases (which ones?), or should this question be closed as too broad (or severely edited)?

Do note the question has been closed once and since reopened. A close vote is in progress. I personally voted to close it, but hey, maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: There are no exceptions. An off-topic question doesn't become on-topic because it's well written. The _only_ reason it got that many votes is because, somehow, it got close to 20k views in 2 days. (wut, how the heck'd that happen?)

Comment: There are questions ([like this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke)) that have a lock with the text "This question exists because it has historical significance". Those questions are off-topic yet not "closed". (Depending on your interpretation of closed of course.)

Comment: It does seem inevitable that a question that provided entertainment to 20 thousand viewers in 2 days as well as inspiration to answerers must be closed.  Of course we are not allowed to have fun, everybody is supposed to plow through the usual dreck.

Comment: @Ivar those questions are old, asked back in the day that much more questions were allowed to exist on SO. Nowadays those questions would have been closed (and possibly deleted) due to them being Too broad or off-topic. Due to the significance of the Q/A, probably measured in views/votes/links, it is locked, meaning it can't be voted on any more or answered and is just left for reference.

Comment: Meanwhile, the question has 2 re-open votes again. This could well become one of those open/close flipping cases, unless a mod steps in and just locks it. Guys, ___Don't vote to reopen that.___ It's too broad for SO, regardless of the attention it got.

Comment: @HansPassant Well actually I really _don't_ like the general orientation SO took years ago when they decided people shouldn't ask again subjective or broad questions. Most interesting questions on SO are old open-ended question with great detailed answers. Now I vote to close such questions because it's now the way it works, but I would be _more than happy_ if this kind of questions is allowed.

Comment: @ken2k [The system supports questions with multiple answers poorly (and is becoming worse at it)](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7770/31260)

Comment: I don't know if the question is too broad or not, I guess it's up to the community to decide. But closing and reopening the question repeatedly won't serve any purpose at this point so I locked it. I'll check back, but in case I miss it, if there's conclusion, please ping me or flag the question to be unlocked.

Comment: With all the close votes aging away, I for sure can find worse questions to close, hence closing this question does not seem to me as a priority. If you need help to find crap just ping me : )

Comment: Doesn't the amount of traffic the question gets count for anything regarding priority, @PetterFriberg? If the question gets re-opened, we're sending a message to thousands of visitors that broad questions like these are _okay_.

Comment: In current situation this "message" seems like the least of our problems, I don't think the OP's of the 1K crap questions every day have ever seen that question. If they took the time to read it probably they would not post all the badly researched questions and then again maybe it would be enough that they read the help section

Comment: [Yesterday quote of the day](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323508/what-to-do-with-broken-but-highly-upvoted-link-only-answers?cb=1#comment346946_323562): **It's upvoted a lot!" isn't the same as "It's a fantastic answer!** (or question)

Comment: Related blog post http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/

Comment: Where is the "too broad" part? It asks about leveraging knowledge of a specific microarchitecture to make C++ code run slower. Yes, there are a number of possible answers. But can anyone name a real programming problem to which there are *not* multiple answers? As usual, this is a case where a bunch of people who know little about the subject have decided, for whatever reason, to dig in their heels. I can't be the only person to have noticed that *none* of the close voters have earned so much as a bronze tag badge in C++ or assembly language.

Comment: @bra You have got to be kidding me. In what way is this question similar to *any* of the examples in that blog post? Compilable ASCII art? Nope. Programming jokes? Nah. The "reddited" issue is a red herring, just like the inflammatory title here. No, the fact that a question has been Reddited does not justify an exception to the rules. I don't think anyone would argue that. But "Peter Cordes posts long, detailed, exemplary answers" is not a reason to vote to close a question, and neither is "there are lots of ways to solve this problem." This question is not fundamentally problematic.

Comment: @CodyGray: Do you disagree with my summary of the question's contents in my answer? The question is extremely low quality and really needs some editing, at very least.

Comment: @Cerbrus you are missing my point. If it didn't get popular, most people would just close it without a second through. Now that it got popular people are doubting their spot on judgment, being sway by groundless arguments. Just look at this meta question. It premises are entirely based on "it got popular, it should be an exception!".

Comment: @Braiam: I agree. Did you tag the wrong @C ?

Comment: @cer Yes, I disagree with your characterization of the question. I cannot argue it is an exemplary question, and certainly there are ways that it can be improved. But compared to most of the junk that gets posted, this doesn't even come close to "low quality." Your judgment of "some noise" is fairly rude, I don't think a sentence of background at the beginning of a question is ever misplaced. We've already decided we don't care if a question is about a homework assignment, and what you call a "code dump" others would call "what he's tried so far." You've asked several of the same caliber.

Comment: @bra In case that was targeted at me, I disagree. Popularity has nothing to do with this, and I don't think it would be closed. I saw that question last night, upvoted it, *then* saw Peter's answer, and upvoted it, and saved the pair in a tab so that I could go back and read it when I had the proper time to devote so I could digest all of the information. Also, the statement "most people would just close it without a second through" is quite concerning to me. I certainly try and give some thought to voting to close. I agree with your last statement, though, this Meta question is problematic.

Comment: @Cerbrus yeah, I wrote my comment twice.

Comment: _"You've asked several of the same caliber."_ Irrelevant. Pointless to bring up here. The fact he's racking his brain over it doesn't add _any_ value. We can't tell what he tried, as he just dumped the code in there without identifying the original code and his attempts.

Comment: The point is that your judgment of the question's quality is clearly being influenced by something other than the question's actual quality, since you wouldn't allow yourself to post questions of your own that you consider crappy and failing to meet the site's guidelines. @cer And you can't have it both ways. Which is it? Is the question "too broad", or is there not enough discussion of what has been tried? Haven't we played out that "what have you tried?" debate on Meta like a thousand times already? Would it really help you to answer the question if you saw the original code?

Comment: @CodyGray Yea, questions I posted over a year ago are totally relevant. By the way, autocomplete: @cer[tab]. Any way, this discussion isn't about me. Stop bringing up my assumed grudge against that question.

Comment: @Braiam: In my answer on this meta question, I argue that it's worth keeping because it's good enough to be of interest to at least a small niche group of people that like microarchitectural stuff.  The fact that a bunch of other people are looking at it and finding it uninteresting doesn't make it a bad question.  Conversely, the crazy amount of votes doesn't make it a great question.  I'm shocked at the popularity of this question.  I think many people missed the fact that it's specifically about microarchitectural reasons, not just ways to write slow C++ (which would be far broader).

Comment: @PeterCordes lets assume for a second that I'm interested in the same kind of stuff, and I'm looking for how to make my C++ run slower using arrays in non-contiguous order, right? So, I google that and I see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7123106/792066), which by what I see on google what I'm looking for! But is not! Darn Google! But look at the 4th result, is this very same question. I scroll directly to the top answer and... it tells me to read some books, how rude! I don't like that one, so I read Jesper's and... the heck? What he's talking about. You are drunk, back to google.

Comment: @PeterCordes so, the fact that is an interesting question, doesn't mean that it will be useful for the rest of us. Even those interested in the very same thing will be lost in a bunch of unrelated information that just makes *more difficult to find what they are looking for*. I feel sad for your answer, but I still feel that with the same answer, you could have answered instead 5 or more questions.

Comment: @Braiam: I agree it's problematic that this niche question got so much attention, and will distort search results.  I don't agree that it's worth closing the question just to de-optimize its search priority.  Re: my answer:   If you skim down my answer, you'd see a section heading about cache.  Are you suggesting I should have led with something other than a link Agner Fog's microarch.pdf?  The Sandybridge section is only ~10 or 15 pages, IIRC.  (Should I make my answer even longer and explain that?)  It's absolutely essential reading for this topic, which the OP specifically thanked me for.

Comment: @PeterCordes no, I'm suggesting that because the question is crappy, your answer doesn't reach those that really need it.

Comment: That aside, crappy questions shouln't get answered in the first place. (Hey, I can stil dream)

Comment: if there is can I have my 'How to eat a fried egg in a sandwich without it going everywhere' answer back on cooking? I still think its the best answer I've ever given.

Comment: There is a certain irony to the fact that the user has garnered three gold badges (Great Question, Stellar Question, Famous Question) for a closed question.

Comment: I find it quite telling of the culture this site has developed that when literally hundreds of questions that are total garbage pour in every day, people managed to dig their heels in to shut down something with +156 and 116 favorites. Obviously it was helpful to *someone*, perhaps not *you*. Possibly not surprising looking at the tag distribution for the close voters.

Comment: I think people were just impressed by the scale of the answer, not by its actual usefulness.

Comment: @WilliamKappler didn't you read yesterday quote? **"It's upvoted a lot!" isn't the same as "It's a fantastic answer!"** (or question)

Comment: @Braiam Strawman. I'm not saying it's a _fantastic_ question, not even that it's even a *good* question (or answer), but that I think there there is a strong motive at play here other than if it is a good question or not. That is further reinforced by my observation that, in the primary language tag (`c++`) I alone have more score than all five closer voters combined. Does that count for anything? I don't know; but it's worth having out in the open. It certainly makes very hard judgements based upon claims of usefulness suspect.

Comment: @William: it seems to me that the strong response is _because of_ the large number of votes, not in spite of it. That number is so huge that it is _clearly_ a result of some outside influence having nothing at all to do with the normal day-to-day quality judgments made by the Stack Overflow community. As an outlier, it is noise in the signal, and noise is something that those who care about the quality of Stack Overflow's content will invest significant effort in trying to remove.

Comment: @WilliamKappler if it didn't gather those upvotes and answer, would your opinion remain the same?

Comment: @Braiam If this popped up in my review queue, I'd flag it for editing. Because in my opinion, all the information needed for the question is there, but it is poorly presented. That is not a valid close reason.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Not liking that a question received outside attention really has no valid bearing upon close voting. Besides, those up votes came from members of this site. If you have an issue with how voting operates, that is a separate topic.

Comment: _"that a question received outside attention really has no valid bearing upon close voting"_ -- that's exactly right, and it's why your argument that the votes somehow indicate something useful with respect to keeping the question open completely fails. _"those up votes came from members of this site"_ -- that a vote came from a member of the site is obvious and irrelevant. There are a wide variety of voting patterns **by members of this site** that are frowned upon, discouraged, or even banned outright. Defending votes on the basis of site membership also completely fails.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Members of the site voted that they considered that question a good question. No amount of twisting that to be "outside influence" is going to change that fact. More importantly, are you suggesting that voting on a question you saw on another site should be banned?

Comment: @WilliamKappler:  _"are you suggesting that voting on a question you saw on another site should be banned"_ -- why would I suggest something that is infeasible to implement? But it is not wise to ignore the harm voting patterns that deviate from the norm can cause, by skewing voting results relative to votes seen on normally-trafficked posts. For example: one unnatural way for me to find posts is to review all of the posts by a specific user; do you believe that it would be fine for someone to do so, and cast votes _on just that user's posts_ based on that review?

Comment: @PeterDuniho What does serial voting have to do with where voters who cast legitimate votes found the question? Serial voting is not bad because you found the posts on a person's user page. By your metric, most canonical questions are harmful because they obtained large numbers of votes from search engines. We'd also have to ban people for the meta effect. As I suggested before, if you have issues with how voting works, address that separately.

Comment: @William: I never used the phrase _"serial voting"_. You'll need to define that term before I will spend any time discussing it with you.

Comment: @William:  _"most canonical questions are harmful because they obtained large numbers of votes from search engines"_ -- not in the same way that this question got its votes. Canon questions get those votes over a lengthy period of time (years), by people who actually _specifically search for_ assistance with the topic. That's a lot different than tens of thousands of people all visiting a single question that they ordinarily would never care about, over a span of mere hours, because it's been advertised.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Why would I need to define it when it is clearly established? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me?rq=1

Comment: @PeterDuniho So you feel assumptions about the reasons for people finding a question are relevant to close voting? I'm sorry, I have no idea what you are trying to argue at this point beyond the fact you want the question closed; I see no reason to continue to bash that issue.

Comment: @William: _"Why would I need to define it when it is clearly established?"_ -- because, as I said, I never used the phrase and so your introducing into the conversation means we need to make sure we're talking about the same thing. Since you're aware of the official definition, you'll note that the behavior I've described doesn't fall under the definition. Again, it's not clear why you've introduced the concept into the discussion.

Comment: @William: _"I have no idea what you are trying to argue at this point"_ -- you'd know, if you'd just go back and look where this started. You are using the number of votes as justification for leaving the question open, and yet reject the notion that the number of votes is relevant to other analysis of the question. I am effectively refuting your self-contradicting claims.

Comment: Since the issue of niche optimization questions that got a lot of attention was brought up by Braiam above, it might be interesting to consider these similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/ http://stackoverflow.com/q/8547778/, http://stackoverflow.com/q/17259877/, http://stackoverflow.com/q/12264970/, http://stackoverflow.com/q/3664272/. Note how they are all C++-based optimization questions that were far from awe-inspiring when originally asked, but received *outstanding* answers and ***oodles*** of attention. Please explain to me how there is a real problem here.

Comment: "Of course, it's an interesting question" For a blog or discussion forumg: yes it is. For a Q&A site: I would say no. Leave them closed.

Comment: Looking at the discussion and ansers, I'm **SO** tempted to vote to close *this* question as being too broad.... ;-)

Comment: See also: the prof who gave this assignment provided some more details, which I've copied into [an answer to this meta question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323690/224132)

Answer (score 87):

**I locked the question while discussions were being held here, to prevent a close/reopen war.**

---

Here's my (personal) take, based on something I read:

> Every rule has an exception. If you happen to find a rule without an exception, then it's the exception to the rule that says that every rule has an exception.

Half of my canonicals are super broad, they're useful, not despite of that, but *because* of that.

The reason we have "too broad" is not only because "the answer would not be useful because it'd be too big", but also because "no one would answer that because it'd take writing a book to do it", only in this case, it was interesting enough to be answered, and answered well.

TL;DR - I'm in favor of leaving it open, despite it fitting the criteria of "too broad".

Comment: This would mean that a _"Do my homework for me"_ question that got a good answer (Which is what this is), would be _okay_. Is that the message we want to send?

Comment: This is not a "do my homework for me" this is a "I have this homework assignment, I did some of it but got stuck on the rest, any tips?" which is still broad, but infinitely better. Also, *homework* specifically isn't a problem, if the question is well written and shows proper research and attempt.

Comment: @Cerbrus.  I kept the homework aspect in mind somewhat when answering.  I think to make really good use of my answer, the OP has to understand some of what I'm saying, since I didn't include any code.  I definitely didn't do his homework for him.  I had a positive impression of the OP's response so far, e.g. "Still working with this, this has probably been the most fun I've had with a project." in a comment on my answer.  So I have high hopes the OP is actually learning things, even if he didn't come up with all the ideas.

Comment: Would you say it's well written? (I wouldn't, see the list in my answer). We can't see what changes the OP made, so we can't really determine what _he_ attempted.

Comment: @Cerbrus Well, that's something that can be fixed via edit from someone who knows how to read his code, or OP himself with an edit.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: Since the OP hasn't responded to _anything_ on his question, I'm starting to doubt he is the original OP of this question. I might be a repost from somewhere else, by someone else.

Comment: @Cerbrus: The OP did comment twice on my answer.  (see my edit of my previous comment)

Comment: You know what, most of my canonicals aren't "too broad". They are specific problems, with specific causes and specific ways to solve. They don't try to cover 100% of the cases, just the 99% that most people finds. http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/ http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/139586/ and http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/205302/

Comment: Having OP edit his answer with what he did is always a good move. That's not what makes this question too broad though. It's that there's potentially a lot of things you can do to a program to slow it down considerably.

Comment: Run it on a Mac, for example.

Comment: @Cerbrus one possible reason that OP doesn't respond to clarification requests is that flood of senseless upvotes from HN lemmings makes them believe that question is okay as is. At score +163/-7 inexperienced user may perceive these requests as boring nitpicking, _"so many users like my question, it should be OK then"_

Comment: @gnat: To add to the list of problems with that question...

Comment: Your answer should include why you chose to lock this question.

Comment: @Laurel - Unilateral decisions are expected to come with explanation from community elected moderators. I would remind you that this *is* meta, and that the "more info" from the person making the decision should be placed right here. Also note, Madara did include that information in this post as requested, albeit without much expansion - but still I appreciated it.

Comment: @TravisJ I don't think there's much to be expanded. I saw the beginning of a closing war, I decided it cut it short, until we reach agreement.

Comment: @Josh that second one actually was a quote, although I can't remember by whom :)

Comment: Okay, sorry, I did a quick Google of it and saw no matches.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha - Which is fair. I am a little curious as to what type of conclusion will be drawn as well because I think there should be some wiggle room available for this type of content.

Comment: @Madara: Since you can edit locked posts, I propose a retitle to "Deoptimizing for the pipeline in Intel CPUs".  Or maybe "Deoptimizing  a Monte-Carlo simulation for ...".  (It's really unfortunate that the OP still hasn't clarified which kind of i7, so we can't say "Intel SnB-family CPUs" or "Intel Nehalem").  Part of the problem with the question is the title.  A lot of people have made generic C++ suggestions, like using Boost for something, that would be slow even on a non-pipelined CPU.

Comment: Hey guys, I guess I'm a little new to Stackoverflow and kind of missed a lot of what happened here.  I didn't think my question would cause all of this and I apologize for any rules I broke.  I plan to post some of my code tonight to show some of the changes once I figure out if the thread can be unlocked.  I apologize I can't answer some of your questions because the lab that was given to us was pretty broad (I.E No specifics of the intel CPU, just I7.)

Comment: @Cowmoogun: I didn't expect anything like this either!  Did you assignment give any requirements on how the code is to be compiled?  Optimization enabled or not is by far the biggest thing, since `-O0` vs. `_O3` makes a huge difference to how source changes will affect the resulting asm.  Also relevant, `gcc` / `clang` / `MSVC` / Intel's compiler?  Any other constraints you can add to the question about what kind of source changes are within the scope of this task would help.  If you have anything short enough to say in comments, Madara could edit it in, or could temporarily unlock it for you.

Comment: @Cowmoogun: When you do post your code, posting as an edit to the question would narrow it down, which some people think is necessary.  Maybe placating them is more important than potentially invalidating parts of my answer that suggest things you already tried, or are incompatible.  Posting your code as an answer would leave the question wide open for other alternatives.

Comment: @PeterCordes Unfortunately he didn't give any specification on optimization so I'm assuming -O0 since we haven't covered compiler optimization options in class.  The following are the complete instructions he gave us when combined with the paragraph in my question:  "Your assignment is the opposite of our first lab assignment, which was to optimize a prime number program. Your purpose in this assignment is to pessimize the program, i.e. make it run slower. Both of these are CPU-intensive programs. They take a few seconds to run on our lab PCs.
You may not change the algorithm."

Comment: @Cowmoogun: Those are all useful details, even though they're not as specific or interesting as I'd hoped.  `-O0` is really braindead, and easy to predict the asm it will make.  And you don't have to worry about defeating auto-vectorization.  Multi-threaded with a shared `std::atomic` counter is still my favourite idea (but non-trivial to implement: I think `#pragma omp parallel` controls the loop counter for you).  The "may not change the algorithm" sounds specific, but isn't really.  Can you expand on that from context from the prev. assignment?  Would storing RNG results in an array be ok?

Comment: @PeterCordes the professor actually just sent an email that based on how he completed the lab we should only see up to a 17% increase so the way I'm interpreting it is that we can't make any changes whatsoever, that we can only reorder the existing c++ instructions.  I plan to clarify with him tonight and I'll post to make sure.  I should have had these answers before posting my questions and I apologize for that.  I want to thank you tremendously, I was having issues understanding pipeline and caching but that first Agner's pdf has been a godsend.

Comment: Glad I could help. :)  BTW, C++ doesn't have "instructions", it has "statements".  Assembly language (compiler output) has instructions.

Comment: @PeterCordes have you seen [Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6166/31260)? "Realize also that **the answer we give you may be completely wrong** for the path that your instructor is trying to get you to follow.  Having previously fought through the problem ourselves, we know and understand when one can jump directly from `il` and when one needs to go through each step of `ijkl` in a process. Our answers may skip over steps that aren't needed *for this particular problem*, but may be critical for understanding the next assignment..."

Comment: @Madara: Can you unlock the question at least temporarily?  I'd like to make some edits based on all the new information provided by the OP and the professor who gave the assignment.  I'd like to get this done before even more people see it for the first time.  I'm going to be at my computer for the next several hours, so ping me if you want to make sure I'm ready to make an edit right away after you unlock.  (I guess I can even compose one ahead of time if you like, but I wasn't planning to.  Let me know.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I've unlocked the question. But if I see it getting reopened/closed I'm locking it again.

Comment: Thanks, edited.  Can you have a look and see what you think?

Comment: It's been re-opened, and has already accumulated on close-vote.  I just put a note at the bottom saying "please don't vote-to-close until discussion on meta is complete".  If people don't respect that, you may need to lock it again, since it only takes 4 more people.

Answer (score 77):

The question we're talking about here is an interesting and unique question.

It is a question to which giving an answer requires thought, and from those answers the reader can learn a lot. It teaches you about machine code, compiler optimizations, and everything that the C(++)/ASM guru might dream of, but is alien to the average developer using a third-generation abstraction-loaded language.

Or, in other words: what was the last time you were hit by [branch prediction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array)?

The type of questions that we have an abundance of, and that I'd like to see closed within seconds without getting an answer: *"How to parse this JSON?"*, *"Why does this SQL query give a parser error while I'm sure it's the correct syntax?"*, *"Write a RegEx for me that matches this input"*, *"How to recognize faces in images?"* and *"[Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)"*.

This is not such a question. Well, maybe the same amount of effort went into the question, but [it's the answers that make this site](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/).

By simply applying the "Too Broad" close reason to questions like this and at the same time keeping questions open that deserve to be closed even more, we're actively discouraging knowledgeable people from spreading their knowledge. Meanwhile, by letting the aforementioned questions stay open and be answered, we're not caring about the long-term usability of the site, but instead even more encouraging the reputation game.

The [rules we currently have in place](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) are the [means to an end](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Means_to_an_end), namely quality control. You can close *any* question by too rigidly interpreting any of the rules, and we should not strive to do that. Instead we should look for the educational value a question, and especially its (potential) answers have.

Comment: This answer could do with less snark, to be honest. It doesn't really strengthen your argument.

Comment: @Cerbrus I might indeed have tried to vent too much in a single answer about too many different things. Don't let that distract you from its core, though.

Comment: _"but just want a nice number..."_, _"they may not be the asset..."_: I'm sure you can think of better ways to convey the same message.

Comment: @Cerbrus like I said, those are things that don't really have to do with this question, but things I identify as a problem nevertheless, and to which I haven't taken the time to pick more carefully chosen words to express them. I'll try to do something about that, later.

Comment: Ah, okay then :D

Comment: "What was the last time you were hit by branch prediction?"  Yesterday.

Comment: +1 you take the words right out of my mouth. I for one appreciated the snark.

Comment: "It teaches you about machine code, compiler optimizations, and everything that the C(++)/ASM guru might dream of, but is alien to the average developer using a third-generation abstraction-loaded language." So does a book. The answers all together would result in a small book. The problem is that all the information is mixed there. Wouldn't it give a much better overview if all this information would be more disentangled in several single more specific Q&As?

Comment: @Trilarion you can write a book about any subject, even mere strings. That does not mean every question about strings is too broad. It's the difference between "How does an HTTP server work" versus "How to implement an HTTP server". The latter is too broad, the former can be answered with a couple of sentences.

Comment: @CodeCaster I agree. What I wanted to say was that in general questions which teaches the reader a lot of things are likely to be very broad and may be better if split into several more focused sub-questions. Better in the sense of better overview and better organization of the information.

Comment: @Trilarion: A simple answer to the question would have been possible, but less interesting, so that's not what I wrote.  That doesn't make the **question** too broad.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm not sure if a simple answer that fully answers the question is possible.

Answer (score 49):

This is one of those cases where we get into this weird ["Telephone Game"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_whispers) situation over close reasons:

- The close reasons were created to reflect problems that folks saw in questions that made them problematic to answer here;
- Folks see the close reasons and go looking for the problems they describe, sometimes without actually understanding the problems that motivated their creation...
- ...And then questions get closed for reasons that don't actually reflect a real problem.

The "too broad" close reason was motivated by [a number of *very* common mistakes made by askers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261353/should-we-lock-read-whole-ascii-file-into-c-stdstring-for-being-too-broad/261370#261370):

> - **There are multiple questions being asked**. Someone is trying to get a two-fer rather than just posting multiple, separate questions. This is closely related to...
> - **Questions that try to cover too much ground**. Asking for help solving a specific problem that arose while writing your OpenGL wireframe renderer is totally legit. Asking for advice on writing said renderer when you've barely more than a list of requirements is too much - a good answer would be a textbook on software design *and* probably include large portions of Foley, van Dam, Feiner and Hughes. These questions often transition gracefully into...
> - **Questions that lack any specificity at all**. Now we're in a situation where there are multiple "correct" answers because **there are no criteria for proving anything *incorrect!*** Questions asking for OpenGL tutorials or help designing systems for which no requirements are provided fall into this category, and often become not just too broad but **overly opinion-based**.

What we got here is a rather specific question that, in spite of its popularity, has managed to attract only 3 answers thus far. The longest answer is just shy of 20,000 characters, which is *pretty long* but still well shy of the 30,000 character limit and unlikely to reach it; in short, there's little evidence that the asker or other readers require the creation of a *textbook* or some *insane quantity of speculative answers* in order to solve the problem presented here.

Let's face it: we're talking about someone's homework problem. They took the time to describe where they were stuck, and others helped flesh it out into something that's clearly captured a lot of interest... but this is *still* just a class assignment, a little problem intended to teach a rather specific concept... ***Not*** the dreaded, "How do I write a social network that also makes waffles?" The most pressing issues with it were some minor ambiguities and omissions in the problem statement, which have now been addressed (apparently by the asker's professor).

In short, it wasn't all that problematic to start with and most of the problems it had have been fixed. Let's congratulate the folks involved on a job well-done and move on to other problems!

Comment: I was hoping you would weigh in on this conversation, and could not agree more with the outlook here. Now I just need to figure out how to bounty meta posts :P

Comment: The OP actually *didn't* show any of his work, and should post an answer.  The question code was the starting point given by the assignment.  From that perspective, it's not much better than most homework questions.  The assignment itself *is* an interesting question for SO, and I basically just answered it instead of anything the OP said.  (Usually homework assignments don't make interesting SO questions directly, but this doesn't automatically disqualify a question.  Other computer-architecture homework questions have gotten upvotes and good/useful answers in the past.)

Comment: Ah, I overlooked that then @Peter. Reading through the revision history, the question indeed started out quite poorly, though the first few edits were sufficient to make it at least understandable. As you say, not a reason to disqualify, but I'd probably have downvoted it if I'd seen it earlier.

Comment: I'll show you when Wafflr takes off!

Comment: Wish I could bounty this. One of the biggest problems on SE (not just SO) is that people forget the reason rules exist and care about the (frequently-subjectively-interpreted) letter of rules more than the problems the rules are supposed to fix.

Comment: I really miss the **There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format**, especially the first part. Now when ELU questions play the single-word-request guessing game we get dozens of zero-effort, one-liner "answers" but folks can no longer point to Too Broad saying that there are "too many possible answers" . Unfortunately. [Case in point](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10493/deleted-upvoted-and-popular-question-why/10494?noredirect=1#comment42700_10495).

Answer (score 23):

#### Update: The professor posted some details, which I've copied to [an "answer"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323690/224132) on this meta.  The original was posted in the wrong place and deleted.

---

It's somewhat broad as-is, but an edit from the OP could fix that.  **It isn't a fundamentally flawed question**, because the too-broadness is in lack of details, not the whole question itself.  Many people are overlooking the fact that it's about microarchitectural slowdowns from pipeline hazards, not C++ in general.  **It approaches a broad topic from a specific angle**.

The OP has only just recently provided further clarifications in comments on this meta post, so it's probably time to unlock the question and make some edits.  Normally it's ok for there to be some delay in shaping a question into ideal form, but unfortunately the question was widely publicized before it was the OP responded, or anyone else improved it.  (A title edit to focus on the pipeline, not C++, would have helped a lot).   I answered on the assumption that it would soon be improved, rather than waiting before that happened.

---

It's interesting enough to enough people to be an exception to the general rule that we don't want a lot of too-broad questions on SO.  Besides the many comments on the SO post, it caught the interest of people on other forums like Reddit and [ycombinator](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11749756), where NKurz posted some results from testing it with different compilers.  I assume that's the same Nathan Kurz who's [posted interesting comments on Agner Fog's blog](http://www.agner.org/optimize/blog/read.php?i=415#423).  So there are definitely people beyond just me with some detailed microarchitectural knowledge and interest that liked this question.  **Obviously it's not going to be interesting to everyone, but no SO question is.**

IMO, this question is **good enough** to stay, even though there are several ways it could still be improved.  It doesn't have to be perfect.  A flawed question can be interesting.  We can [decide on a case-by-case basis to allow things like this without opening the floodgates](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/).

---

In this case, what makes the question interesting is the idea of de-optimizing without simply bumping up the iteration counts or bloating the code.  Also, having to justify your pessimizations as "diabolically incompetence", rather than *intentional* pessimization is really interesting.  This is the new idea that people want to think about.  The specific code in the question isn't what makes it interesting.

There are also aspects that can't change at this point, but would have made it a better question: e.g. a different choice of source-code to de-optimize.  Code that didn't spend so much time in `exp()` and `log()` would make much more sense.  Also, we can invent reasons to store things in memory, and memory stalls are a huge deal, but having some kind of data structure in the first place would have been nice.

Apparently the assignment was not intended to be very complicated, and it was only a "second semester" computer architecture course.  I assumed that it must be a pretty advanced class to be studying Intel pipelines, because they are seriously complicated.

---

Many people have made suggestions based on the title ("deoptimizing a C++ program") that would slow down even a non-pipelined CPU.  e.g. use Boost to get the compiler to generate some slow stuff using very few source lines.  I think it's *these* suggestions that are off-topic and contribute to the impression that "too broad" is really a problem.   OP hasn't done a good job of ruling out such source changes, though.  This meta question got me thinking I should edit the question title to be more specific, but the question is locked ATM.  (Thanks for not locking the answers, I might have more ideas to tighten up my long & rambling answer).

---

> "obviously too broad" ... (see the first answer, which has more than 15k characters)

Too Broad applies when the *minimum* length of a sufficient answer is too big.

The fact that a long and detailed answer is *possible* isn't a problem, as long as short answers that don't go into detail could be good enough.

This isn't the case when a long answer would be *required* to correct all the misconceptions in a question.  Or for many homework questions to an otherwise trivial question.

**I think the fact that I could give a fairly detailed answer that covers many of the bases in only 2/3rd of the maximum 30k chars doesn't support the too-broad argument at all.**

I could find 15k chars of things to say about performance considerations in many answers to direct questions, like [SSE horizontal sums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996764/fastest-way-to-do-horizontal-float-vector-sum-on-x86), or [how to zero a register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/which-is-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and).

---

I had no idea this question was going to be popular!  I've made several edits to shorten it and present the same information better, not just keep making it longer.  One of the most important recent changes was including a `TL;DR` table of contents / summary of the more plausible suggestions that the OP could justify with the proper application of diabolical incompetence, and not just outright malice / obvious pessimization.

I've been toiling away writing answers with detailed microarchitectural justification for choosing one way of doing something over another (e.g. with [SIMD vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996764/fastest-way-to-do-horizontal-float-vector-sum-on-x86)) for a long time now, and this is one of very few that's caught the interest of anyone outside of [computer-architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/computer-architecture) or [x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x86).  Another one being [this one about popcnt of bits below a position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34407437/what-is-the-efficient-way-to-count-set-bits-at-a-position-or-lower/34410357#34410357).

I tend to write long/detailed answers, because I hate leaving out information that is relevant.  I've had positive feedback from many people about the microarch details and technical depth of my previous answers, and I'd much rather write for an audience that appreciates that.

My approach to answering was to consider all the ways I can think of to stall or slow down a Sandybridge-family pipeline, and consider those stalls from the PoV of this program.  So a few paragraphs are spent on stalls that we can't reasonably expect to create, like LCP stalls or self-modifying code.  Or partial-register stalls, which are only a really big deal on Nehalem (the first i7).

Anyway, so **even though I cover a lot of ground, I tried to tie every point back to the specific angle the question is coming from.**

My answer as it stands now is kinda long, and could be ordered better.  I wish SO markdown allowed collapsible sections to allow interesting asides to not get in the way of more important text.

Comment: _"I tend to write long/detailed answers"_ Ya don't say ;-) (Not my -1)

Comment: _"interesting enough to most people to be an exception to the general rule"_. What makes you say that? Out of __20k__ visitors, only __100__ (0.05%) favorited it. 0.75% upvoted it. Those are really insignificant numbers. Reddit doesn't provide a snapshot of the linked page, so a person will have to visit the page to see if he finds it interesting or not.

Comment: @Cerbrus: I say that because *I* found it interesting, and so did the many other people that left comments with ideas, or discussed their ideas ([and actual experimental timing results](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11749756)) on other forums.  Also, the ratio of up to down votes on the question is currently 163:7.  My answer has attracted only 2 downvotes so far, so clearly out of people that did vote, the response has been much more positive than negative.  (I know more people upvote more often than they downvote, and many people decided it wasn't worth an upvote.)

Comment: Discussion on other forums is pretty irrelevant here. Different rules, different crowd. How many of those 163 upvotes come from users that don't regularly visit SO? How many of those upvotes are just joining in upvoting an exceptionally high voted Q/A pair? If the question were actually _good_, it'd have gotten 10 times the amount of upvotes.

Comment: @Cerbrus: I reworded my answer to say "interesting to *enough* people", since most people don't actually delve into microarchitectural details.  I agree it's of niche interest, but it absolutely is interesting to those of us who like this sort of thing.  De-optimizing is a novel challenge.

Comment: Peter, what do you think about migrating it to code review? Maybe that's a good alternative?

Comment: @Cerbrus: It might be a better fit there.  There are [convincing arguments that "help me optimize this code" questions belong on codereview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37227679/looking-for-improvement-to-a-procedure-to-determine-a-sorted-arrays-median#comment61996973_37227679).  I'm kind of resistant to that because codereview usually focuses most on human readability aspects of code quality, not on performance.  (and the chicken-and-egg problem of having most of the existing x86 asm / performance stuff on SO, but that's not a good argument.)

Comment: Better ask on the Code Review Meta site if they're okay with "deoptimizing" questions. That may not be their cup of tea. Aside from that, I think (as you have said before) that this is an Intel microarchitecture question in disguise, which is a better fit for Stack Overflow. I also don't really like the implicit suggestion to migrate this question to another site just because it makes certain people "feel funny." If it truly runs afoul of our guidelines, it should be closed outright, not pawned off on our neighbors. Of course, I don't think it does, it just caught someone's Monday morning ire.

Comment: Perhaps this is just not the right forum anymore for *out-of-the-box* questions and *detailed, multi-aspect answers*. This being said, I am not quite sure what other forum would welcome such posts. Perhaps CS.SE?

Comment: @Matsmath: This specific question is definitely not computer science.  I've had positive responses to my detailed and technical answers on other questions, even though they're long, so I don't think that's the problem.  All the real objections are to the question, which is problematic.  Some people have used answer-length as a metric for too-broad, but that's bullshit because I could find 15k chars of stuff to say about performance considerations for a lot of SO questions.  I look at it as "a detailed answer only took 2/3rd of the allowed space". :P

Comment: Editing the question and making it more specific is surely a good way. But then, what to do with the existing answers? I would leave it closed and start again with a better, more localized question. Maybe even leave the code out and first ask for possible de-optimizations of the microarchitecture. Then asking for each of these if they can be applied to the code. Would give very clear Q&As.

Comment: @Trilarion: You need some kind of code or at least description of what kind of code.  Otherwise the right response would a link to http://agner.org/optimize/ and a downvote for "lack of research effort".  And probably also a too-broad close reason.  I mean, code can be memory-bound, or bottlenecked on one of many other things microarchitectural things.  The kind of "more specific" that I was hoping for wouldn't invalidate the answers.  I'm not keen on the question being changed to include some specific de-optimization attempts, since the starting code is nice and short.

Comment: **I wish SO markdown allowed collapsible sections** Please vote here: [Collapsible Code Markup](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302078/collapsible-code-markup)

Answer (score 21):

#### Reposting [the professor's response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37403418/be-diabolically-incompetent-deoptimizing-a-c-program)

It's not really an answer to anything, but it should go somewhere and does explain some things.

---

I am the professor who assigned the program in the "[deoptimizing a C++ program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37361145/deoptimizing-a-program-for-the-pipeline-in-intel-sandybridge-family-cpus)" thread. Because Stack Overflow does not appear to have a way of directly emailing the moderator, I am posting this question to answer some of the items raised in the other thread.

The lab CPUs are i7-4770s, 8GB.

The students have been exposed to the CPUID instruction and how to determine cache size, as well as intrinsics and the CLFLUSH instruction.

The actual assignment had two options -- the Monte Carlo simulation shown by the student who submitted it, as well as Whetstone. The comments about cache de-optimization were mostly oriented towards the Whetstone option.

The ground rules were intentionally vague. This was supposed to be a fun assignment which made people think about what they knew about the i7 architecture, which we had been covering for several weeks, concentrating on cache and pipelining issues. We had also done a lab using x87 floating point. Any collection of changes was not excluded from the assignment, including compiler options. Inline assembly was fine, and use of MMX rather than x87 was slower in one implementation. Writing your own square root algorithm was announced as being outside the pale.

This is a second semester architecture class using the Hennessy and Patterson book at a community college.

Since few of my students will actually go on to design hardware, my focus was on how to best make use of the hardware in a high level language. I am impressed by the variety and technical depth of many answers here.

I would prefer not to have any further discussion, but hope that the foregoing information extends the learning opportunity for the people who have dug into this problem.

With my best regards, Hoping to remain anonymous...

---

Comment: It's generally agreed that the Intel P6-family of microarchitectures ended with Nehalem (the first i7). Intel Sandybridge is regarded as the first of a new family of microarchitectures (all of which are sold under the i7 brand name), due to substantial changes to the internals. e.g. physical register file instead of storing operands in the ROB. uop cache. 2 load ports. Substantial changes to the internal uop format (can no longer micro-fuse indexed addressing modes). The decoders are different, too: producing 4 fused-domain uops per clock max, instead of 4 instructions -> 7 uops max.

Comment: So please don't call it "the i7 architecture", because that's nonsense. It makes little sense to lump SnB-family in with Nehalem but not Core 2 or earlier.  When Nehalem was new, "Core i7" was sometimes used (even by Intel) as the name for the CPU family, but then Intel released SnB i7 CPUs...  A lot of the basic stuff like partial-register stalls, partial flag stalls, and register read stalls work the same or very similarly in PPro and Nehalem, but differently in SnB-family. **Just call it the SnB-family pipeline**.  Or the Haswell pipeline if you're talking about your lab computers.

Comment: "use of MMX rather than x87 was slower in one implementation". I'm not surprised, since MMX is integer-only. You'd have to use fixed-point math to do Monte-Carlo with MMX. Although perhaps you meant SSE?

Answer (score 14):

I am the original poster of that question. I'm in the midst of finals weeks and completing projects so I've been a little absent minded while I wait for clarification from my professor tonight. I'd like to preface this that I appreciate all of the help in answering the question and I want to apologize that I did not provide more information the Lab given to us was intentionally vague in terms of what specific CPU.

From what I understood his instructions as, we were to make the Monte Carlo simulation slower by just reordering the instruction set which the most voted answer went way beyond that (to the benefit of learning). The resources provided have been incredibly useful so far.

I'm new to this community and I really appreciate the help I've received, if there anything I can do to answer any more questions, please don't hesitate to ask. Still getting used to Stack Overflow so I'm sorry if I miss anything.

Comment: Don't worry about it, if *we* can't agree on something, how can you be expected to?

Comment: You can only modify the C++ source, though, right?  You don't get to reorder the asm instructions manually.  Even if you could, aggressive out-of-order microarchitectures like Intel's Nehalem and Sandybridge-family will still find the parallelism unless you change the program logic so it has different dependency chains.  When the question said "using your knowledge of the i7 pipeline", I assumed it meant most of what I put in my answer was already covered in your class, and you just needed "diabolically incompetent" ways to justify causing these stalls!

Comment: (continuing the off-topic discussion from comments on Madara's answer):   Sounds like my answer wasn't at all what the assignment was looking for.  I don't think as many people would have found that sort of answer interesting, since it would probably just be some extra store-forwarding round-trips from `g++ -O0` output, the kind of crap I complained about in the optimizing-with-`-O0` answer I linked near the top.

Comment: @petercordes Honestly your answer was the best answer in terms of helping me understand the pipeline and in the end that's what's going to help me complete this assignment.  I don't want the answer to the problem, I just wanted some breadcrumbs to help lead me towards the right path and your answer with the resources led me there!

Comment: I was mostly commenting to laugh at how uninteresting the lab assignment sounds, compared to how interesting your question was.  I think knowing exactly why code runs fast on a certain microarchitecture is really interesting, and I'm glad the massive popularity of the question got some more exposure for Agner Fog's guides, as well as some of the interesting stuff I had to say in the answer.  I've noticed a trickle of votes for some of my other answers that I linked from that one, so it's neat to see people are actually following the links I dug up and put in :)

Answer (score 13):

Hard rules have no exceptions, that's why they are hard rules. For instance, a 600 character limit on comments is a hard limit. But when we say *too* broad, we already admit up front that it's not a hard rule. It's a soft, subjective rule.

So let's look at that clarification: "there are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format". Nope, that's just two soft rules.

This is important, because an "exception to the rule" is a concept which tries to soften an otherwise hard rule, to make put one specific case on the other side of a sharp border. Example: Twitter is no longer counting URL's in its tweet length. This is a hard exception to a hard rule. But when the border is already fuzzy and subjective, there's no need to soften it.

So, back to the specific case at hand. Are there infinitely many unique answers? Not really. There are a few clear areas: ISA, registers, cache, memory bus. Is an answer necessarily too long? No, not even when the top-voted answer is too long (can't really blame the question for that).

(This doesn't mean I think it's a particularly well-written question, but's that is a down-vote reason instead of a close reason)

Comment: You already identified 4 possible areas for the answers to focus on. Other users could probably come up with a couple more. There's not a _single_ clear "right" or "best" answer. -> Too broad.

Comment: What is your bar for too broad then?

Comment: *Of course* answers can come up with multiple aspects of a question to focus on. That's almost guaranteed for any real-world programming problem, which are the types of questions we purport to entertain here. Certainly it is true for all *interesting* questions. The only questions with only one possible answer are "debug my code" questions, where the answer is that "you dereference a null pointer in line 42". Everyone agrees they dislike those, but then they fall victim to the typical Meta myopia and start proclaiming ridiculous standards where such questions would be the only ones allowed.

Comment: @Cerbrus: A question that would attract 4 answers, for each of those areas, would not be too broad. And that's assuming no answer addresses both. "Too broad" IMO is so many possible answers that the paginating logic can't show all the numbers of pages anymore.

Comment: 4 areas to answe in. Each possibly having multiple approaches (answers), @MSalters.

Comment: I agree with this 100%. Also I think this reasoning applies well to [this question of mine on programmers.se](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/317398/can-a-media-decoder-player-be-implemented-entirely-in-c).

Comment: @marc This isn't really the place to have a discussion about your Programmers.SE question. If you want to have that discussion, you should bring it up on [their Meta](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/). Personally, as I see so often, I think your title was what attracted most of the close votes. Question: "Can this be done in C#?" Answer: Yes. And so people think, dumb question, can't reasonably be answered, need to find a close vote reason. Pick anything, "too broad" sounds good. You should've asked more like "What specific limitations of C#/.NET would make it difficult to..."

Comment: One could split the question into 4 questions: Like: How to hit ISA with this? How to use registers badly with this? How misuse the cache with this? How to slow down the memory bus with this? These would all have been really good questions.

Answer (score 6):

Would this question have been appropriate if the inverse question had been asked?

"How can I improve core i7 pipeline performance with this code?"

Is this "obviously" too broad? Microarchitecture optimisations surely are an appropriate topic for Stack Overflow so the topic should not be discounted out of hand. There may be a set of specific techniques used to optimise a given program for a given architecture. Just because there exists more than one or two techniques does not automatically make something too broad.

An unbounded set of answers or techniques certainly **is** too broad though. So how many correct answers `N` is too many?

```
Not too broad < N < Too Broad
```

What is `N`? Does `N` change given the topic? I feel this is the major sticking point here - what is "too broad"? I don't think this particular question meets that definition. The answers are focused, immediately relevant, useful to future visitors, and are not contradictory (answer 1 can be used alongside answer 2).

The popularity of a question or answer shouldn't have anything to do with whether or not a question/answer is on topic. The usefulness of a question and answer do. "Too broad" is subjective in some cases, so calling this question "obviously" broad is wrong IMO.

If the argument here is that the quality of the question is bad but the content is obviously useful, then err on the side of not closing, and either improve the question or encourage others to improve the question. Default closing should be reserved for truly awful questions with no redeeming qualities or very clearly off topic question.

Moderators should default to leaving a question open if there is significant disagreement. I think locking the question in this case was right to stop the ping ponging, but I would have preferred it to be locked in an open state (if that's possible) considering the topic wasn't being abused by drive by answerers.

Locking/closing questions sends certain signals, of which many in this community and others interpret as being negative. Questions in a grey area that are locked send very negative signals to participants in a question as well as external communities that may be following along. By all means lock/close anything not in a grey area (discussions for example), but err on the side of caution for those that are.

Comment: To counter your example, there are specific and enumerable scenarios in which one should use a linked list, but I would say that you could've strengthened the "not too broad" question with an example that made a callback to that.  Otherwise, you're going to get a lot of confused people thinking that it's fine to use ArrayLists for their FIFO structure.

Comment: You're right. I originally had many examples under each heading and trimmed it down. I'll make an edit.

Comment: Actually it's not totally obvious that "optimize this working code" is on-topic for SO.  [There are convincing arguments that such questions belong on codereview.SE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37227679/looking-for-improvement-to-a-procedure-to-determine-a-sorted-arrays-median#comment61996973_37227679).  I'm not sure if the "for an i7 uarch" changes that.  Codereview doesn't currently have many questions or answers focused on perf (AFAIK), and definitely few about x86 asm.  That chicken-and-egg argument doesn't really hold water, though, since new sites have to start somehow.

Comment: I consider the code review site useful for architectural and style questions, not specific optimisation questions. That's a point of view that's probably subjective though. But when something is subjective, I still argue that default open is better than default closed, until some kind of consensus is reached. The original question could definitely be improved, but the focus on i7 pipelining grounds it firmly in SO territory IMO.

Comment: "what is "too broad"?" Practical definition of "too broad": if a single, comprehensive answer to the full question would be too long. And the way out is to split the question into smaller ones.

Comment: "I consider the code review site useful for architectural and style questions, not specific optimisation questions" You may only be talking about the actual interactions you've seen there, but ["Performance" is very much officially on-topic at CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and (from the same link) "Architecture" is explicitly _off_-topic. Design and architecture are topics that [Programmers.SE] would love for you to ask about.

Comment: @Trilarion I don't agree with that definition. That implies that information should be cut if it doesn't fit into a yet undefined length. The accepted answer could have been trimmed down significantly, but he went the extra mile by providing references and suggestions that weren't explicitly asked for but were still related and *useful* to the asker and future visitors. The close reason targets questions that require answers that are too many or too long. In this case the answer didn't *have* to be long. The author chose to make it so.

Comment: @JoshSmeaton With what definition would you agree? I see it as the practical approach to things. The length of a good, comprehensive answer is important. If a good answer would be the length of a book it would probably not be suitable for Q&A. Also I'm not sure if going the extra mile and delivering a much longer answer than necessary was a good idea here because in the end less people will read the whole thing (but those who do will learn a lot, so it's okay).

Comment: @Trilarion I guess I agree with the "single comprehensive answer" part *if* the answer required the length to explain properly. If an answer could be shorter but the answerer chooses for it to be longer that's not a problem with the *question*. As yet though, no one has defined a length in terms of words or characters as to what constitutes "too long". As Peter points out, he didn't reach the limit that SO allows, which is a hard limit. Should there be a soft limit too, and if so, who determines whether the hard or soft limit should apply.

Comment: @JoshSmeaton As I see it, the "too broad" close reason is a soft limit and it is decided by the users of StackOverflow. In rare cases though there is no consensus and then a close/reopen war would start. In that case moderators have to step in. I completely trust that they have a soft definition of "too broad" and can apply it here based on the discussion and all the argument for and against. So in this case: because we cannot agree, moderators have to decide.

Answer (score 3):

"Too broad" is already a soft criteria. No need to add exceptions to it.

Also, we do not emphasize enough that question closed as "too broad" can be split into smaller topics and then are on-topic.

For the example question: While it is an interesting topic the answers are a long read. I would have preferred the splitting of the question into several sub-questions. I think this would result in better questions and answers and a better read overall. However it might be a bordercase of "too broad" - in principle one could write whole books about processor and compiler technology just for this single question.

"Too broad" just becomes too broad if one (or a few) full, comprehensive answer(s) would be too long (too long is again a soft criteria). In the example if the question remains open the information is unlikely to get organized better. I would either leave it closed or split the question into smaller parts.

A good focused similar question is [branch prediction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array) and a split of the example question into similar focused questions would be preferable in my eyes.

Answer (score 1):

The question under discussion is a fine question to ask someone, and the answers are *great* answers **to that question**. However, the question is unlikely to help other readers in its current form because the entire thread is specific to the code in the question.

There are good paradigms and practices suggested in the answers that *could* be applied to any/all code, but in their current form, aren't applicable outside of the context of this question. So barring a rewrite of the question (and, therefore, the answers), the question should be closed and probably deleted. I would vote to close it, and probably wouldn't vote to *un*delete it.

Comment: Parallelizing with diabolical incompetence (shared atomic loop counter) is a very general-purpose de-optimization, and so is a store-forwarding stall.  A lot of my answer would still apply with different sample code to be de-optimized.  The purpose of the question is to understand what can stall an Intel Nehalem or SnB-family pipeline, not good C++ coding practices.  The question title is unfortunate, because people seem think the question is broader than it really is, or aiming at a different purpose.

Comment: @PeterCordes I've told this to other people before, but if you see a question title that can be improved, improve it! If you think the question is really about something else, and can edit it to clarify what the question is asking and/or improve the scope, without invalidating the existing answers, *please* do so! I agree that the title is pretty horrible. The issue with the *content* of the post is that it doesn't really go into detail about what the issue is outside of the context of the OP's code. Right now the question seems like a code-anti-golf question... not really useful to readers.

Comment: I often do edit question titles to make them more specific.  I didn't realize that people were going to miss the point of the question, and only clued in to the title really being a problem after it was locked and this meta question opened.  Before that I was too busy revising my answer to be better organized for the benefit of the boatloads of people that were viewing it!

Comment: @PeterCordes: If you have a better title in mind already, it might be worth dropping a comment for Madara Uchiha here proposing it. Mods can edit locked posts.

Comment: You seem to say the question is "too specific"? I think, the problem with the question is rather the organization of the answers. There is too much information spread around. One has to read a lot in order to get a clear picture. Would have been better if the question would have been split into several sub-questions.

Answer (score 1):

A post which seemingly helped so many users and garnished so many views while being well written is not a problem in my opinion.

Closure is supposed to be a tool that is used to combat low quality or behavior leading to negative effects such as spam or duplication. I don't see low quality here, I don't see spam or even the "broken window" side effect going forward.

The question is clear, there is code showing the exact scenario, and the question of what else could have been done is probably poorly worded but in the end resulted in a rather fantastic answer.

I support this question, and do not want to see it closed or deleted. I wish all questions were as intricate as this instead of asking about null exceptions, failed include references, array out of bounds, how to create an entire feature, how to fix an exception that literally states how to fix the problem in its message, etc. etc. etc.

Focus on removing garbage, not value.

Comment: stronger indicator... [yeah sure](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/)

Comment: What are you trying to say @gnat? Use your words. Your link from Jeff Atwood has this to say "**what we try to do at Stack Exchange is make sure that questions and answers are *popular for the right reasons* -- because they are amazing resources for learning from your peers**"

Comment: in this case upvotes only indicate that question was advertised to 20K readers at HN, nothing else. Your points made after "Closure is supposed to be..." etc look worth thinking about but part about _indicator_ makes really little sense to me

Comment: @gnat - There are questions advertised on the hot network list at all times. While this may provide a small benefit, the result you seem to indicate is not wide spread which means this activity is related to the content and not the advertisement. Increased awareness is a double edged sword, and can easily result in a post receiving negative voting. There was even the idea recently that downvote threshholds could be used to assist in closure. The implication is that upvotes would indicate remaining open.

Comment: I'd like to compare 5 close votes to 156 upvotes.

Comment: @gnat Attention does not invalidate +/- ratios. More attention to a question offers equal chances for bad questions to be downvoted.

Comment: chances are never equal @WilliamKappler. To start with, there are 3x more users who can _only upvote_ (rep 15 to 125) than those who can choose whether to vote up or down. This already gives much better chances for advertised questions to get positive score. And only 1/4 of those who can vote down are able to see [meta-tag:split-vote-count], meaning 3/4 of them are more likely to follow "snowball effect" of a high positive score without even noticing that someone else voted down

Comment: @WilliamKappler you may want to read the quote of yesterday, look for it on the comments on this question. Also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285471/re-opened-after-appearance-on-hacker-news?lq=1#comment152124_285471

Answer (score 0):

Let's turn the question around: If it didn't get popular, would you believe it deserved some kind of exception? If your answer is "no", then of course it should not. Quality of the posts are measured by their content in isolation. Not by the [amount of votes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323603/is-there-such-a-thing-as-exception-to-the-rules?cb=1#comment347114_323603), [nor the](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258433/792066) [presence of answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/227044/213575), or [other](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285471/re-opened-after-appearance-on-hacker-news#comment152124_285471) [factors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285474/792066).

Now, let's strip the question down of any distractors, like this:

#### My version of the question

> ## Task
>
> I've doing something, but I don't tell you what, I would like you to
> do it, here's what you need to do:
>
> > requirements
>
> Here's the code you would be working with:
>
> ```
> [code]
> ```
>
> I've made some chances, but again, they are secret, that seems to be
> doing something, but I'm not sure what else to do to fulfill the
> requirements. A point to the right direction would be awesome, I
> appreciate any responses.

Tell me, is that good enough content that deserves to be treated differently?

Comment: Dude. You have 3k Rep. Surely you've heard about the case of "Closed due to historic significance", eh? Tell me what that is, other than an exception from the rules. It isn't solely about the question, atleast not imo, the answers raise the value the question offers by a lot.

Comment: @Seth It's locked, not closed and it is *the* exception, not some invitation to make further exceptions for new content, which is exactly what the locked message says. Besides, a lot of people object to historical locks even as they are (saying it makes them hard to maintain their old bad questions) http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289381/

Comment: @Seth "Surely you've heard about the case of "Closed due to historic significance", eh?" It was posted **less than 72 hours ago!** What in the world is "historic" about this question? Our lack of timely moderation to prevent this whole issue altogether? Because, otherwise, I don't see the relationship.

Comment: @Braiam My point is that - in some cases - there are exceptions. Sure, partly they're due to the standards that were applied back then, but some are "spared" due to the value they bring, despite fitting the scope of a close reason. Just saying, it's not always black & white.

Comment: @Seth what value you see in the question? Nobody has showed it to me. And as I [pointed out to Peter](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323603/is-there-such-a-thing-as-exception-to-the-rules/323620?noredirect=1#comment347159_323603), no one will find it.

Comment: @Braiam The most valuable part for me is that you can read through the answer(s), and look out for things like this in your code for example. It's the same as "Good" vs "Bad" practices, knowing both benefits you more than just knowing the good practices.

Comment: *"what value you see in the question?"* Ugh. Maybe I'm taking this too personally, but that just rubs me the wrong way. I'm not surprised someone whose top tag is Javascript doesn't find the question valuable. I see *plenty* of value in the question, and both myself and Peter Cordes and others have repeatedly made arguments about the value that they see in the question, and more importantly, in the answers it has attracted. I'll grant that "potential answers" are, in general, a bad metric to judge question quality, but we don't have to speculate here. Don't miss the forest for the trees.

Comment: @CodyGray yeah, you are taking personally, you just recurred to an *ad hominem* attack instead of a sound argument. Congratulations. Why can't a guy which "top tag is javascript" push an argument about the quality of a question, which according [to even the answerer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323629/which-demographic-population-interacted-with-the-deoptimizing-a-c-program-qu?lq=1#comment347443_323648), **you also have no qualification to emit an opinion**, if we follow your "argument", since your top tag is c++, instead of those more relevant ones.

Comment: Hmm. It wasn't meant as an *ad hominem*. I didn't mean that you're stupid because you're a Javascript programmer. Just that someone who spends most of their time in a scripting language probably can't understand the appeal of a question about low-level, architecture-specific issues. I'm certainly not saying you can't have an opinion. Rather, I'm musing about why you still can't see the value that's been pointed out repeatedly. I've already commented elsewhere why I disagree with your "version" of the question, and I feel like you are judging the question like a machine, rather than an expert.

Comment: @CodyGray I don't spend "most of my time in a scripting language", in fact, my career is not even a STEM, my score in the tag is due a different matter, so any idea about myself are erred. And, again, nobody has pointed out the value outside "is a interesting question", which I repeatedly argued that it doesn't matter since [nobody will ever find the information](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323603/#comment347160_323603). Yes, is a interesting brain teaser, that I don't argue. My argument is that interesting information that can't be shared is not interesting anymore.

Answer (score 0):

> it's an interesting question, and people that answered it put a lot of effort into their answers.

The world is full of interesting programming questions. Programming is an interesting topic, and there is a practically infinite number of topics for discussion that would interest programmers. But the vast majority of those questions don't belong on Stack Overflow.

Indeed, for better or for worse, the most interesting questions are exactly those that don't belong on Stack Overflow. Because of their breadth, and also because often they have a strong opinion-based nature. These are the kinds of questions that we'd love to sit around with our friends and colleagues chatting about for hours, exploring every nook and cranny of the topic. But those are exactly the kind of rambling, wandering, impractical questions that are explicitly not on topic on Stack Overflow.

And frankly, it frustrates me that with a bit of gaming the system (like publicizing one's off-topic questions in a high-traffic off-site location), one can ignore the documented intended design and goals of Stack Overflow and come out way ahead like this.

It's true, we have such a hard time keeping up with the constant flow of sludge, and that's in fact why a meaty question like the one being discussed here appeals to the base instincts of the Stack Overflow community. It's so tempting to take a break from the daily grind and dig into a question like this one.

But that doesn't change the fact that the question is far too broad to be on-topic here on Stack Overflow. The guidelines are clear, and **closing a question like that is always the right thing to do**. Beyond that, personally I think it's unfortunate that a couple of people that showed such poor judgment in terms of compliance with site guidelines have been so richly rewarded in reputation points, as it dilutes whatever meaning those points have. But, oh well…it's not really that big of a deal. They broke the rules, they got away with it, but as long as the question gets closed to prevent additional clutter and time-wasting on it, what's done is done and it's not worth worrying too much about that.

Comment: It's only "far too broad" if you missed the part about doing it by stalling the pipeline in an Intel CPU.  When I answered, I read it as a novel twist on the kind of microarchitecture question that I geek out on.  I didn't think it would have mass appeal.  (And probably it shouldn't have gotten so much attention, but the title made some people miss the specific nature of the question.)  It has its faults for sure, which the OP should have fixed, which is why I left a comment to that effect before answering.  The broader topic is water-cooler fodder, but the actual question is specific enough.

Comment: The question, ___as is___, is too broad. Meaning it should be closed as "Too broad". The OP can still edit the question if it's closed to make it specific.

Comment: This [SO blog post from 2010](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/) covers this case: A question that's interesting but bends the rules.  2010 is ancient history in SO terms, though, so maybe things have changed and now we really do hate fun.  You do make a really good point that being interesting is not sufficient justification for an exception, though.  This question would be better in a format where replies to posts were themselves full-fledged posts that could include formatted code blocks.

Comment: Anyway, the OP has posted some clarifications in comments here on meta, so the original question can be unlocked and edited with improvements any time now.  Usually there's a lot more time for the OP to clarify before a marginal question is closed as too-broad, but the OP was busy with end-of-term stuff and the question got tons of attention very early.

Answer (score -3):

There should be no exceptions. An off-topic question doesn't become on-topic because it's gotten 20k views in a short time.
The only reason it got that many votes is because it got over 20k views in 2 days. This was possible because the question appears to have been linked on [/r/programming](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/4kmcxp/deoptimizing_a_c_program/), and some other sites.

At ~150 upvotes, only ***0.75%*** of visitors actually upvoted the question. Only 100 (0.5%) favorited it. That doesn't really indicate the question is *good*.

The massive amount of views isn't an indication of quality, either.
Reddit has a *massive* userbase. If a user wants to see if a topic is interesting or not, he *has* to open the link (question, in this case). Regardless of if the user stays or not, the view count will increase.
<sub>(In the 2 hours this meta question existed so far, the question's gotten 1.2k views.)</sub>

---

That all said, the question is textbook *"Too broad"*:

> *There are either **too many** possible answers, or good answers would be **too long** for this format.*

The question itself consists of:

- Some noise,
- Followed by a (school-) assignment,
- A code dump,
- And a request to review / improve (mangle) the code.

**Any** other question like that, that didn't get those views would've either died a slow lonely (digital) death, or get closed before long.

Comment: Many of the viewers probably aren't regulars on SO, or aren't in the habit of voting.  Clearly a lot of people are interested, and [it has spawned discussions in other forums, too](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11749756).  I answered the question while it was still at about +3 or something, IIRC.  Before I started getting more ideas from comments, my answer was [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37362225/5): already fairly long and detailed.  Even the very initial response to the question (from SO regulars) was positive, with more upvotes than close votes.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Even the discussion on there has some users saying it's __too broad__ for SO. The problem is that the question got that much attention from outside of SO, at very early stages. If it didn't get the attention, I wouldn't be surprised if it had died a silent, quiet death...

Comment: Most questions have a very small ratio of upvotes to views.  I'm not arguing it's a great question, just good enough to bend the rules for (and hope it is made less broad).  Clearly the voting has been inflated, but beyond +25 or so, it feels like more of a lottery than an actual measure of question quality.  I basically won the rep lottery by being in the right place at the right time to give an answer to this question that people liked, but I don't think that matters.  The hugely inflated number of votes isn't the main argument for keeping this question.

Comment: Then what is, @PeterCordes?

Comment: Since this last comment has some upvotes:  See my answer on this question. tl;dr: Because it's a good-enough Intel-microarchitecture question that is interesting and useful in helping people that want to learn more about what specifically can make code run slow on modern CPUs.  It's not as broad as some people are claiming.

Comment: The _question_ isn't good at all by SO's standards. It's a code dump in which it is unclear what the OP attempted, and what the original code wants. There are a load of possible answers, and none of the possible answers is better than the other, unless you combine'm all into 1 long answer. That one long answer, as I'm sure you're well aware, is _massive_. That doesn't really work in the question's favour.

Comment: @PeterCordes:  Just so you're aware, [data run by bluefeet](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323648/1079354) suggests that many of the viewers *are* active, *do* vote, and have an average reputation of 6K.

Comment: If you think the format of the question was particularly bad, then spend the effort improving the writing of the question, comment so the asker can improve the writing, or comment and wait for someone else to improve the writing. Closing a question that has formatting problems is awful, unless the question is obviously so low quality that there is no redemption.

Comment: You've said in [several](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323603#comment347235_323623) [comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323603#comment347108_323615) that the upvotes are largely due to attention on external sites, but there *is* a (low) minimum rep requirement to be able to upvote at all - so any voters must have already had an SO account with some useful contributions already. The claim that external views = votes following a trend is somewhat misleading (especially in light of the data from bluefeet).

Comment: @JoshSmeaton: I couldn't improve the post if I wanted to. It's locked.

Comment: @Bob: The rep requirement to be able to downvote is significantly higher. (125). _anyone_ can quickly get the 15 rep required to upvote.

Comment: I have just done a quick check of the percentage of upvotes of the 500 questions that have >150 votes, the average is 0.29% of people upvoting, the median is 0.15. 5 & 0.02 being the min and max, In that context I would say that 0.75% is a well upvoted question

Comment: @MichaelB: did your check consider the short timespan?

Comment: @Cerbrus I didn't, it was just the raw vote / views count. Mostly I was curious of it to counter the "really insignificant numbers" claim that you made. It has a higher percentage of votes than most other questions with a similar vote count. I don't see how that would be any different whether that happens over a day, a week, or seven years, it is still people reading the question and hitting the up arrow as a result of believing it showed research effort and was useful and clear. ;)

Answer (score -3):

**First of all:** In **my** opinion the "Too broad"-reason for Close-Votes is problematic itself, simply because the value of a question is - again, my opinion - not only defined by the question itself, but also by the answers contributed.

Sure, if the question didn't receive *any* attention whatsoever, chances are it'd be closed without discussion by now, but it has received quite a lot of attention over the course of **2 days** (*20k views, quite a number*), and **really good answers**!

To me, this question is at most borderline-"Too broad". It's a clear question asking for possibilities to deoptimize a given code-fragment, and the community - judging by the amount of upvotes/views/favorites - likes this question or finds it interesting enough to upvote it.

Possible factors for that are that

- it's very interesting to see a question like this (most questions nowadays go for optimization instead of deoptimization)
- it helps people who want to increase their knowledge regarding slow processes

Sure, upvotes are by no means a universal indicator of what's good & what's not, **but they do indicate interest**. A few people put quite a lot of effort into answering this question, and I think the outcome makes this Q&A valid for the scope of SO.

**Just to answer a few arguments of people voting to close this:**

- it should be closed since the top answer has 15k characters

  - As far as I know the max. amount of characters for answers is 30k, so why would you use half of that as justification of closing it?
- "only" 0.75% of the visitors actually upvoted this question, and "only" 0.05% have addet it to their favorites

  - Let's be real here. I don't know the +/- count since I do not have that privilege unlocked yet, but the fact that it has a score of +150 clearly shows what the viewers thought of this question, eh?

**All in all:** I don't agree with closing this, simply because it carries value, it's appreciated by a large fraction of the community & it is something else. It's the exact opposite of what you see nowadays ("How do I make this code better?"), and that's refreshing.

Comment: The +150 is pretty meaningless considering the amount of views it got. Any Q/A that gets enough views will accumulate votes. Users that don't generally visit SO are often inclined to "Join in" on whatever the current voting trend is.

Comment: _"it's appreciated by a large fraction of the community"_ This is not true. Only a _tiny_ percentage of viewers seem to "like" the question. _"It is something else"_ So? That doesn't mean it should just stay.

Comment: @Cerbrus Yeah. Right. Frequently viewed Q&As do get a lot of votes, but they tend not to have a score of +150 :) *A tiny percentage of viewers seems to "like" the question* Yes. The funny thing is just: You devalue the upvotes by saying "there should be more if it's good!!!1111!" & just **ignore** the fact that it **has a positive score of 150**. Jesus, please, stop enforcing your own opinion like that.

Comment: A positive of 150 means squat on a textbook "Too broad" question that got 26k views in 2 days. You're enforcing your opinion just as much as I am.

Comment: Cerbrus is right that the huge number of votes are not a valid justification for keeping the question open.  It *is* a niche question where good answers will center on obscure technical details.  It's not really a C++ question, it's an Intel microarchitecture question that for some reason got way more views than normal.   (Partly the C++ title, probably also the novel suggestion of de-optimizing instead of optimizing, which I agree is very neat).  I think it should stay open, but my reasoning (detailed in my answer on this meta) is very different from yours.

Comment: "(most questions nowadays go for optimization instead of deoptimization)" I guess even this homework question goes for optimization in the end. It's a know your enemy kind of question.

Answer (score -5):

For "too broad" specifically, the close reason is about the (possible) answers, not the question itself.

"Too many possible answers" really means something like "everybody could create a new answer that shares nothing in common with the rest of the answers". The fact that there can be more than one answer (or subanswer) should not be categorized like this.

"Too long for this format" is just a nice way of saying "it would be a waste of anyone's time to answer this."

---

From those perspectives, the question deserves to be left open, since the answers that exist are high quality, though perhaps the question should be edited slightly to fit the type of answers that are on-topic.

Answer (score -19):

I voted to close that question because rules have to be obeyed. Otherwise SO would have turned into a mess. So, no exceptions!

On the other hand, not only the question is *interesting*, but the answers are also very good (*I learned a lot!*).

To my mind, we may just leave it closed since it's obviously too broad. I wouldn't recommend its deletion, though.

Comment: "I voted to close that question because rules have to be obeyed". You are of course free to vote to close, but I would hope you had a better reason than that. "Rules must be obeyed" I just can't agree with. There are many situations where breaking the rules is the best cause of action. I just can't accept this as a reason.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: I'm pretty sure that first line was sarcasm.

Comment: @Cerbrus, that reading doesn't seem to correspond well with the fact [that ForceBru actually did vote to close as "Too Broad"](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwEUN.png).

Comment: So, he was serious :P

Comment: @Cerbrus, I was serious. Seriously, this question _is_ too broad, and if something is too broad, a serious man should vote to close that. Being even more serious, this question is not serious enough to stay opened (I mean, that "they gave me an assignment and I was wondering how I could do it better" is not serious).

Comment: That I can agree with

Comment: In many ways, Stack Overflow IS a mess already. It's hard to find anything, and there are many crap questions that stew for *years* because there's just so much stuff. I really wish that I had more close votes, but I try to use my precious few on the things that NOBODY wants.

Comment: Then why did you ask [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28115724/)? It is also quite broad, I can think of *many* different ways to generate large random numbers in C++, and so could the answerers. Same thing [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29829338): lots of ways to convert an array into a hash. And presumably [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29847504), though I can't say for sure, I don't know any Python. I'm not trying to pick on you, I'm just saying that either (1) you don't apply your "too broad" rule to all questions equally, or (2) this question really isn't "too broad."

Comment: @CodyGray, if you know any good solution that wasn't mentioned in the answers to my questions, you can write an answer, I'd be grateful if you did that :) To my mind, _broad_ questions are difficult to answer because one could write a whole book to discuss all possibilities. E.g.: how do I make my code slower? How do I become a web designer? How to learn C++ as fast as possible? My questions ask for _code_, and are relatively simple (I mean, the code one may need to write won't probably exceed 20 lines), so, in my opinion, they're not so broad. I think _too_ broad /= _possibly_ broad.

Comment: I don't necessarily have anything *better* to offer as an answer to your question(s). But neither do I have anything more to contribute than Peter's answer already does to the question under discussion. The point is that any reasonable question can be considered "too broad" under the criteria you're trying to establish. There are lots of different ways to solve a problem. I don't know how all these people are missing it, but you have to read past the title of the question before deciding to close it. It is not a generic "how do I make my code slower" question, there are specific constraints.

Comment: You could certainly argue that Cowmoogun's question asks for code. They clearly only avoided doing so because they were concerned that people would then vote to close as a "do my work for me" question. You just can't win. I can write a book about just about any programming question, so that is a horrible standard for "too broad." I wish people would stop throwing it around like it meant something. No, you're right, the potential answers to your questions are probably relatively short, but that is neither an attribute of the question nor does it make your questions any less broad.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not trying to attack you. You don't need to defend your questions. I think they are perfectly valid. I'm just saying, I don't see the distinction between your questions and this question with regard to the "too broad" criteria. Except for the whole not looking past the title problem, and thinking that the entire question is "How do I make C++ code run slower?" Not only would that be too broad, more importantly, it would be a suck-ass question that I'd vote to close all day long. It fails the interesting and useful test.