# Which demographic population interacted with the "deoptimizing a c++ program" question?

Tags: support, specific-question, statistics

There's a claim in one of the comments:

> Discussion on other forums is pretty irrelevant here. Different rules, different crowd. How many of those 163 upvotes come from users that don't regularly visit SO? How many of those upvotes are just joining in upvoting an exceptionally high voted Q/A pair? If the question were actually good, it'd have gotten 10 times the amount of upvotes. – Cerbrus [4 hours ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323603/is-there-such-a-thing-as-exception-to-the-rules#comment347108_323615)

Which brings forward a interesting query, how different demographic groups feel about [*that* question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37361145/792066)? If we can separate all the users that interacted with that question in:

- Votes, per reputation and account age
- Votes, per referrer
- Votes, per amount of score in the relevants tag: c++, optimization, cpu-architecture

It can shed some lights about which tiers of users push towards one or another direction. Of course, the amount of reputation and score in tags, can be used as way to deanonymize the users votes, but I think that due volume this could not be a problem... otherwise, I think SE can feel free of not providing this information.

Comment: So, who said that we can't ask questions tagged [specific-question] and [statistics]?

Comment: Can we please not extrapolate the happenings around one particular question to extract future decisions?

Comment: @CodeCaster what...?

Comment: What insights do you intend to gain from the answers to this question then? Why are you asking what you ask for?

Comment: @CodeCaster to see which users we need to weed out? If there's some miscommunication between meta, the help center and the general population? Because, I like to know what is passing through the minds of others? Why else?

Comment: I'm in favor of keeping that question. Therefore I should be "weeded out".

Comment: @Braiam oh yeah, there's a huge disconnect between meta users and the main users, but that issue is not trivially discussed in one question, and absolutely not using the question you've asked.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's rare that we are asked to supply stats for a specific question but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37361145/deoptimizing-a-c-program) has received a lot of traction in a short amount of time, so I understand the curiosity.  I'll provide some very high-level totals for consumption.

A total of **170 users** have voted on the question.  The average reputation of the upvoters is about 6k, and 11k for the downvoters.  Average reputation isn't the greatest metric, so I looked a bit closer at the breakdown by rep level.

#### Votes by Reputation

The post has garnered a lot of upvotes by users in a every rep level checked:

```
Rep        Total Votes 
---------  -----------  
15 - 125   20         
125 - 500  24         
500 - 1k   19         
1k - 2k    27         
2k - 3k    16         
3k - 5k    14         
5k - 10k   21         
10k+       22
```

There have been very few down votes on the post, but here is a breakdown by rep level.

```
Rep        Total Votes 
---------  -----------  
1k - 2k    1          
2k - 3k    1          
3k - 5k    1          
5k - 10k   2          
10k+       2
```

#### Votes by Account Age (in months)

Most upvotes on the post have been given by account older than 3 years (36 months).

```
Months   Total Votes 
-------  -----------  
0 - 6    6          
6 - 12   9          
12 - 24  19         
24 - 36  21         
36 - 48  20         
48 - 60  34         
60+      54
```

Again, there are very few downvotes but most are coming from accounts that have been around for longer than 3 years.

```
Months   Total Votes 
-------  -----------   
0 - 6    1          
36 - 48  2          
48 - 60  1          
60+      3
```

#### Votes by Tag Score

I only pulled some details based on activity in the [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag, since it is the largest tag with the most users associated with it making it more difficult to track back votes to users. I grouped the data by users with a Total Score of <=0, and > 0 in the tag, to show users who have contributed positively to the [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) versus those who haven't.

Total Tag Score by Upvoters:

```
Total Score Total Votes 
----------- ---------- 
<= 0        53         
> 0         110
```

Total Tag Score by Downvoters:

```
Total Score Total Votes 
----------- ----------     
<= 0        4          
> 0         3
```

#### Observations

- Most of the users voting on the question have had an account on Stack Overflow for a substantial number of months (36+ months), so it is not new users voting on this post.
- 66% of the users voting have a positive [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag score, so more than half of the voting doesn't appear to be from drive-by users not contributing to the tag

Comment: For clarity, are the "rep levels checked" (15-125, 125-500, 500-1k, etc.) chosen by you, or does the system make those bins? The distribution is almost even across the bins, so I wondered if they were in fact partitioned _based on the votes_.

Comment: Seems like it's just broken down by major privilege thresholds?

Comment: @JoshCaswell those are the normal rep I use when looking at the data, it tends to be broken down by privileges. 125 is when users get DVs, etc.

Comment: @Troyen that's typically what I use when doing these types of breakdowns.

Comment: Wow, that's interesting and totally unexpected.

Comment: It's not *really* a C++ question.  It's more about the compiler *output*, i.e. `[assembly]` / `[computer-architecture]` / `[x86]` / `[intel]`.  At least that's how I read the question.  Also highly relevant `[performance]` and `[optimization]`.  I just got access to the SO analytics tools, so maybe I'll play with that soon.

Comment: I was in two minds about this question. To me it appeared broad - perhaps *too* broad, as it was an open ended question. On the other hand, I could see it may have some merit, and the most excellent answer proves that. I decided to not vote up *or* down and let others decide. That's not reflected in your breakdown - perhaps you can dig something out of the number of views?

Comment: @PeterCordes " I just got access to the SO analytics tools, so maybe I'll play with that soon" hardly useful in this case, since the data bluefeet provided is anonymous by design.

Comment: @PeterCordes That's possibly true but the smaller tags could make it easier to identify users who voted.  The `c++` tag was on the question from the beginning and it's a widely used tag so I used that for a breakdown.

Comment: @RadLexus Not sure what you mean, what other numbers are you looking for?

Comment: @RadLexus I don't think that the system works that way, from what I read. I think that it only stores the IPs of recent views to ensure one person's not just refreshing the page a lot.

Answer (score 4):

> - Votes, per reputation and account age
> - Votes, per referrer
> - Votes, per amount of score in the relevants tag: c++, optimization, cpu-architecture

Should any of these points be relevant for upvotes/downvotes instead of the actual questions content?

---

> How many of those 163 upvotes come from users that don't regularly visit SO?

Well, let's vivisect that:

> - Votes, per reputation and account age

Someone trusted was upvoted (devil shits on biggest heap, or the post was really helpful for many viewers).

> - Votes, per referrer

Drive by votes are likely gotten from referrers, low rep users with less insight how voting should work are likely to upvote crap also.

> - Votes, per amount of score in the relevants tag: c++, optimization, cpu-architecture

You mean score of the voter? Same as the 2nd point IMHO.

---

Sorry to answer with counter questions, but I think that's another important point to consider.

Finally votes are anonymous, **and there are no (public) SEDE queries available** to track these backwards by properties available from the voters profile.

---

> It can shed some lights about which tiers of users push towards one or another direction.

Well, I was often contemplating about the *butterfly effect* my vote will have on a post. The most time I'm concluding like

- If there's a reason to close, I almost always also DV the post
- If it's worth it, I'll garnish that with a comment
- Rarely I close vote without a downvote along, because the post formally matches all the policies we gave in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), but is too broad or another custom reason might apply

---

Well, getting upon that specific one you mentioned:

[**Deoptimizing a C++ program**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37361145/deoptimizing-a-c-program)

It's only helpful for someone who was asked solving that silly task given from specific course material (and the question was seen several times. Sorry I can't find the backup anymore, but I'm pretty sure I've seen it).

That's not a ***real world*** programming problem, and that the question was closed is the correct reaction.

The most probable audience that *profits* from the question and answer is just a bunch of students, that like to cheat to get their exams right.
It's questionable, if we should encourage such at Stack Overflow.

Probably also the professor asking for such stuff should be kicked ass, because *"to put the cart before the horse"* is probably the wrong teaching strategy.

It might be a reasonable exercise to explore how you can get wrong with assumptions about CPU instruction caching, but as asked it's not really useful.

---

Well, I at least agree, that it would be interesting why there are so much upvotes and get some statistics about these.
But as mentioned it's actually not possible, unless a mod (or even SE dev) would let have us insight about that.

Comment: **"and there are no SEDE queries available"** what is this question tagged with?

Comment: @Braiam Well, how do you consider extracting _statistics_ without SEDE queries? And how would you aquire these _statistics_ without having the _voting_ information related to the _voters profile_ actually?

Comment: *Der Teufel scheißt immer auf den größten Haufen* Yep, putting that one in my back pocket.

Comment: Err.. I hope a Shog or something blue appears that can answer my queries, like they have done http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/statistics/topusers

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The SE team has provided statistics for various things before and tend to do so at request provided a decent reason is given and the stats aren't compromising. If they don't feel they can provide this information without giving who exactly voted away, then they'll likely say so and not provide the data.

Comment: @Will THX for _honouring_, appreciate it from the king ;-) ...

Comment: @Kendra Well, then it's still questionable if they would create a statistic for a [tag:specific-question].

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm not saying I agree this is a good request or likely to get answered, but you had pointed out in your answer that it can't be queried in SEDE. That's completely irrelevant as the team can provide the information if they feel it's a good/reasonable request. You also asked in a comment, _"Well, how do you consider extracting statistics without SEDE queries?"_ The answer is the SE team would have to provide the statistics.

Comment: @Braiam _"Err.. I hope a Shog or something blue appears that can answer my queries ..."_ Well, sometimes you're getting only silly, dizzy coffee :-P ...

Comment: @Kendra _"The answer is the **SE team** would have to provide the statistics."_ So you mean the SE devs have to cheer in actually?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Any of the team that has access to look at the data. Shog, Bluefeet, whoever. Of course, a lack of chipping in could in theory be an answer of "We're not providing that" or it could be a case of "We never saw that" or "We saw that and got busy and forgot to come back to it." But, yes, someone who _works for_ SE would have to give the information for this particular request.

Comment: On the gripping hand, the data is here....