# Why is this question OK?

Tags: discussion

Why is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532980/reproduce-the-unix-cat-command-in-python) OK?

Usually questions that are "too broad" or "opinion based" are downvoted and closed almost instantly.

Yet this one is getting upvotes and answers, despite there being clearly many possible answers, and the concept of "better" being opinion based.

Is it because the question calls for answers that are a short attractive piece of code?   Or ...what?

Comment: It was from 2012 and it seems to be useful to people. We have more pressing problems than that question...

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that this question in particular is a pressing problem.  I'm interested in how the guidelines should be applied.   There appears to be a concensus that this question is OK.  I'd like to understand the basis for that.   Or whether in fact, it's agreed that its clearly not OK, and just exists despite that.

Comment: Again, it's from 2012. The guidelines were slightly different back then. And it does seem to be helpful to people -- when questions are more helpful, people tend to not apply the rules as stringently.

Comment: kthx. "Don't use old questions as calibration for on topic" is a good rule.  I honestly didn't notice that till you pointed it out: someone must have modified it because it popped up in my question list.

Comment: Nah - there's something else about this question that makes it more OK.  Maybe it's because the initial attempt was quite reasonable, or the goal is interesting.  Otherwise [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39541916/how-can-i-improve-this-javascript-code) would be OK for the same reason.    Actually - I guess it's because it's not a "totally basic" improvement question, like the latter one.

Comment: It is a clear violation of the "we're not allowed to have fun" rule.  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323603/is-it-possible-for-some-too-broad-questions-to-be-exceptions-to-the-rule

Answer (score 1):

Summary of resolution in comments: it may or may not be OK, but **it is not suitable for calibration of OK-ness because it is old**.